# How do i statically build Wolfs cpuminer-multi?

Tags: cpu-mining, mining, linux

The miner is : https://github.com/OhGodAPet/cpuminer-multi

The question is how do i do a static build which would allow me to compile the miner only once and run it on several diffrent machines.

Im using ubuntu 14.04 but i can switch to any operating system if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here are well written instructions for a static compilation of cpuminer:

https://lxadm.com/Static_compilation_of_cpuminer

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest suggestion would seem to be that which is offered at: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/issues/97 .

"autotools build does create a static library when the --enable-static flag is passed to ./configure.".

Comment: The user is not trying to compile a static *library* - they are trying to compile a static application. Thus the link you posted does not answer the question in any way.